# MATLAB Read HEX Data from text file

Tags: matlab, hex, text-files

I have a text file with HEX values as follows:

```
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 9F 8E 7F 6E 1B 2C 3D 4E 5F 4A 5B
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 9F 8E 7F 6E 1B 2C 3D 4E 5F 4A 5B
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 9F 8E 7F 6E 1B 2C 3D 4E 5F 4A 5B
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 9F 8E 7F 6E 1B 2C 3D 4E 5F 4A 5B
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 9F 8E 7F 6E 1B 2C 3D 4E 5F 4A 5B
...
```

**EDIT**

The format definition for the data is as follows:

```
Word(16bit) |Name | Type | Bits | Value | Units | Notes
0-1          Name1  N/A    15-10
             Name1  N/A    9-2
             Name1  N/A    1-0
2            Name2  N/A    15-0
```

So it turns out I got more information about the definition file. It turns out that there are different types of words where they are further broken down to smaller chunks of bits. For example Name1 is 1 16-bit word, but in three parts and Name2 is a 16 bit word in just one part. My question now is for Name1 type words, does it make more sense to use hex2dec, or should I convert from hex to bin, then convert the chunks of binary to dec? I can't think of any other way of getting bit15-10 from a hex2dec output. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Does the format specification mention endianness by any chance? If not, maybe your assumption to convert 16'bit groups is the closest you can do without more information.

Comment: No that's all the info that I have

Comment: It won't "fit" even if you use 16 bit for each of the fields "Word | Name | ..." as you have 7 fields and you have 16 columns in the data block.